# JMeter - Control the Iteration count with in a Thread Group which has Multi Actions

Tags: jmeter

No.Of Iterations in a thread Group is : 3

Thread Group Name from the below screenshot is : TCByEmployee

Thread Group performs various steps using If Controller

I want to Achieve **"Loop Controller-TCbyEmployee-Login by Employees"**
& **"If Controller-TCbyEmployee-Login by DH"** should start Next Iterations once it's completes **"If Controller--TCbyEmployee-Login by PA**" Iteration 1

Now the issue is :  **"Loop Controller-TCbyEmployee-Login by Employees"**
& **"If Controller-TCbyEmployee-Login by DH"** continues the up to Iteration 3 before  **"If Controller--TCbyEmployee-Login by PA**" begins

Please see the below screenshots
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question in its current form doesn't make any sense, you need to either re-phrase it or provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

So far I can only inform you that:

1. Once started each JMeter thread (virtual user) starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
2. When thread executes last Sampler in the Thread Group it starts over from the beginning
3. If there are no more Samplers to execute or loops to iterate the Thread is being shut down.

---

- If you're looking for a way to implement a [GOTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) statement - take a look at [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller), this way you can change the flow from upside down to some custom
- Also be aware that threads (virtual users) are absolutely independent and if you think that the execution order is broken might mean that another user executed another sampler at that moment

  [image]

And last but not the least, [don't run your test in GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)